# BIRT runtime not found

Tags: maven, spring-boot, birt

I have an application, where I am introducing Spring boot. It has some BIRT reports defined as .rptdesign files. To handle them, following mapping was defined in web.xml.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>EngineServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet- class>org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.BirtEngineServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>EngineServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/output</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
    <version>${eclipse.runtime.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
 </dependency>
```

I am trying to configure the same with spring-boot. Maven dependency is the same.

I tried registering the mapping via ServletRegistrationBean:

```
@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean exampleServletBean() {
    ServletRegistrationBean bean = new ServletRegistrationBean(
      new BirtEngineServlet(), "/output/*");
    bean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    return bean;
}
```

This code does not compile as class: BirtEngineServlet cannot be resolved to a type. I tried with adding more BIRT components to Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
    <artifactId>report-engine</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.report.engine</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0-20070705</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt</groupId>
    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Other option that I tried, was defining my own BirtEngineFactory. The code compiled, but BIRT Runtime classes (i.e BirtException) were not found during runtime, with NoClassDefFoundException thrown.

Any suggestions how to configure BIRT with Spring boot using Maven?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is as follows:

pom.xml

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>Maven Repository</id>
      <url>https://mvnrepository.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

...

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
  <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
  <version>4.4.1</version>
  <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.poi</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.orbit.mongodb</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
    <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Repository matters and runtime version matters - tried with various and it failed - only 4.4.1 worked for me.